# A matrix and a column vector containing indices, how to iterate with no loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, octave

I have a big matrix (500212x7) and a column vector like below

```
matrix F         vector P
0001011          4
0001101          3
1101100          6
0000110          1
1110000          7
```

The vector contains indices considered within the matrix rows. P(1) is meant to point at F(1,4), P(2) at F(2,3) and so on.

I want to negate a bit in each row in F in a column pointed by P element (in the same row).

I thought of things like

```
F(:,P(1)) = ~F(:,P(1));
F(:,P(:)) = ~F(:,P(:));
```

but of course these scenarios won't produce the result I expect as the first line won't make P element change and the second one won't even let me start the program because a full vector cannot make an index.

The idea is I need to do this for all F and P rows (changing/incrementing "simultaneously") but take the **value** of P element.

I know this is easily achieved with *for* loop but due to large dimensions of the F array such a way to solve the problem is completely unacceptable.

Is there any kind of Matlab wizardry that lets solving such a task with the use of matrix operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it qualifies as *wizardry*, but [linear indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) does exactly what you want:

```
F = [0 0 0 1 0 1 1; 0 0 0 1 1 0 1; 1 1 0 1 1 0 0; 0 0 0 0 1 1 0; 1 1 1 0 0 0 0];
P = [4; 3; 6; 1; 7];
ind = (1:size(F,1)) + (P(:).'-1)*size(F,1); % create linear index
F(ind) = ~F(ind); % negate those entries
```

Answer (score 4):

> I know this is easily achieved with for loop but due to large dimensions of the F array such a way to solve the problem is completely unacceptable.

You should never make such an assumption. First implement the loop, then check to see if it really is too slow for you or not, then worry about optimizing.

Here I'm comparing [Luis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55577602/7328782) and the trival loop:

```matlab
N = 500212;
F = rand(N,7) > 0.6;
P = randi(7,N,1);

timeit(@()method1(F,P))
timeit(@()method2(F,P))

function F = method1(F,P)
   ind = (1:size(F,1)) + (P(:).'-1)*size(F,1); % create linear index
   F(ind) = ~F(ind); % negate those entries
end

function F = method2(F,P)
   for ii = 1:numel(P)
      F(ii,P(ii)) = ~F(ii,P(ii));
   end
end
```

Timings are 0.0065 s for Luis' answer, and 0.0023 s for the loop (MATLAB Online R2019a).

It is *especially* true for very large arrays, that loops are faster than vectorized code, if the vectorization requires creating an intermediate array. Memory access is expensive, using more of it makes the code slower.

**Lessons:** don't dismiss loops, don't prematurely try to optimize, and don't optimize without comparing.

Comment: Good lessons, all of them! I got similar timing results on R2018a

Comment: It wasn't just an assumption as I tried for loop and it took way too much time to perceive such a solution as acceptable (358.4 secs). This might be due to the fact that I actually work in Octave environment which seems to have difficulties with loop-oriented code. I'll bear in mind your suggestions, tho. This is very interesting, thanks.

Comment: @GameDevMike: Indeed, if you had tagged the question Octave instead of MATLAB I wouldn't have given you a hard time about avoiding loops. :)

Comment: Yeah, I should have, but every cloud's got a silver lining – optimization lessons learned (I thought loops are always slower tbh) ;p

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
xor( F, 1:7 == P )
```

Explanation:

- `1:7 == P` generates one-hot arrays.
- `xor` will cause a bit to retain its value against a 0, and flip it against a 1

Comment: That is a very short solution, nice! `P` *must* to be a column vector in this case.

Comment: I will also point out, that in theory octave also has an experimental jit compiler, but this needs to be enabled when building octave itself (and has been known to be prone to compilation errors). Also, if one _really_ needs optimised code, octave has a very powerful `octfile` interface, which enables you to write compiled c++ functions fairly easily (but, yes, this is typically beyond the scope of most casual octave programmers, even if the API makes it easy to write with only fairly rudimentary knowledge of c++)

Comment: Do you have any insight as to when the JIT work will be completed in Octave? I'm curious to see it in action, but I'm too lazy to compile Octave myself. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo nah, it doesn't seem like something that is too actively worked on from what I can tell.